# Get location of file that is defined as alias

Tags: powershell, alias

I defined some permanent aliases (within my "profile.ps1") to files I need to access regularly like

```
set-alias -name myfile1        -value N:\somefolder\morefolders\anyfile.txt
```

Now I want to get the directory where the file is located, but I'd prefer not to define additional aliases. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `Get-Alias` to retrieve the alias
2. Use the `Definition` property to get the target path
3. Use `Split-Path` to get the directory

```
$alias = Get-Alias myfile1
Split-Path $alias.Definition -Parent
```